# using pexpect pxssh twice on two different ports

Tags: python, ssh, pxssh

I am trying to connect via SSH using pxssh to a remote device, however one of these devices is SSH port 2222 and one is 22. I know I can change the hardcoded value in pxssh.py to either 22 or 2222 but I don't know how I can do both at the same time.

I looked at the pxssh login() function and tried putting 'port' after password, so when calling pxssh I could specify the port required e.g

pxssh.py file

```
def login (self, server, username, password='', port, terminal_type='ansi',original
            _prompt=r"[#$]", login_timeout=10,
            auto_prompt_reset=True, ssh_key=None, quiet=True,
            sync_multiplier=1, check_local_ip=True):
```

calling pxssh login from my file

```
s.login(server, username, password, port)
```

however that error'ed with

```
SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument
```

I then thought I could duplicate pxssh and have pxssh22.py and pxssh2222.py

```
if something:
     from pexpect import pxssh22
else:
     from pexpect import pxssh2222
```

each specifying a different hard coded port number however that kept erroring with when called:

```
try:
    s = pxssh2222.pxssh()
    s.login(server, username, password)

except pxssh2222.ExceptionPxssh as e:
NameError: global name 'pxssh2222' is not defined
```

How could I use pxssh to access both port 2222 and 22. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As no one else has any ideas, I fixed this by moving the port argument in the pxssh.py file and then rearranging the s.login function call to include port.

modified pxssh.py file

```
def login (self, server, username, port, password='', terminal_type='ansi',
            original_prompt=r"[#$]", login_timeout=10,
            auto_prompt_reset=True, ssh_key=None, quiet=True,
            sync_multiplier=1, check_local_ip=True):
```

modified login call to allow for port argument.

```
s.login(sshIP, "root", sshPort, sshPass)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can provide port as an optional parameter when calling the `login` method.

```
  s = pxssh.pxssh()
  s.login(server, username, password, port=2222)
```

Comment: Wiht port unable to login ssh connectoin: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/pxssh.py", line 261, in login
    spawn._spawn(self, cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 596, in _spawn
    assert self.pid is None, 'The pid member must be None.'
AssertionError: The pid member must be None.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pxssh.html), we can simply use default arguments and port of our will.

```
host = 127.0.0.1
user = root
password = toor

s.login(host,user,password, terminal_type='ansi', original_prompt='[#$]', login_timeout=10, port=2022)
```